# Trying to understand functor but did not understand what that code exactly doing

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Following code add map method to function prototype so we are able to map our function, which basically composing map function with the result of mappable function. I understand that

```
Function.prototype.map = function (f) {
  const g = this
  return function () {
    return f(g.apply(this, arguments))
  }
}
```

But did not understand the following

```
const Box = x => ({
    map: f => Box(f(x)),
    fold: f => f(x),
    inspect: () => `Box(${x})`
})

const nextCharForNumberString = str =>
    Box(str)
    .map(s => s.trim())
    .map(s => new Number(s))
    .map(s => s + 1)
    .map(s => String.fromCharCode(s))
    .fold(s => s.toLowerCase())

console.log(nextCharForNumberString('  64  '));
```

Could you help me to understand that. Box is a function Box(x) and I am losing track after that.Why those parenthesis ( ({ })) and how that thing is working.
Thanks for your time and understanding,

By the way first code is taken from 
https://medium.com/@dtinth/what-is-a-functor-dcf510b098b6
Second code is coming from egghead.io's functional javascript first lesson (it is a shame I just stuck in the first lesson)

Comment: The parentheses are there because the syntax `x => {...}` does not work to define a function that returns an object literal (probably because it overlaps with the syntax for code blocks). You need the parentheses to make it work.

Comment: Got it, so instead of initializing an object inside the function and adding all the necessary properties this guy just returning the object literal. So those parenthesis has nothing to do with immediately invoked function syntax or those parenthesis just let him return the function without invoking it and functions are objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to inflate the code out of es6 syntax.

```
function Box(param) {
 return {
    map: function(fn) { return Box(fn(param)); },
    fold: function(fn) { return fn(param) },
    inspect: function() { return `Box(${param})`;
 }
}
```

an example: `let a = Box(1);` returns the object from the `Box` function and gives you access to `a.map, a.fold, or a.inspect`

`a.map` takes a function as a parameter. let's say that function returned the value passed in `plus 1`

```
function myFunction(n) { return n + 1 };
```

you could call `a.fold(myFunction)` and the returned value would equal `2`. This is because our initial `param` was 1, and our function takes that parameter as its argument and returns.

Basically `fold` applies whatever function to your `param` and returns it.

`map` is similar except that it returns `Box(myFunction(1))` which returns a new `Box` object with a `param + 1` since that's what our function mutated our param to.

`inspect` simply outputs a string that tells you what the current value of param is.

Overview:

```
function add1(n) { return n + 1 }

let a = Box(1); //param is 1. 
a.fold(add1); //translates to add1(1);
a.map(add1); //translates to Box(add(1)), aka, Box(2)
a.inspect(); //translates to "Box(2)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it make more sense. That syntax confused me a lot.

Comment: @MehmetNoyanAydin Yeah it's weird that they started out introducing a new concept with the most terse script as possible. I would've been confused too!

Comment: I think that answer my question, marking it as answer. Thanks again. Now got the thing, after spending a day that is a good feeling.